# open excel immediately without saving excel to local path using interop.excel

Tags: c#, excel

I need to open excel immediately without saving excel to the local path using interop.excel

Below are my research result but not sure it's correct. I would be appreciated if any help.

```
using Excel1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel1.Application xlApp;
Excel1.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel1._Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlApp = new Excel1.Application();

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel1._Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
    Excel1.Style style = xlWorkBook.Styles.Add("NewStyle");
    style.Font.Name = "Courier New";

    for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        Excel1.Range rangeStyles = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A:XFD");
        rangeStyles.Style = "NewStyle";
        cells = lines[i].Split(new Char[] { '\t', ';' });
        for (j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cells[j];
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? If it's a working code and you want to improve it, then you need [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. The code appears to create a new Excel file, does some editing in the file and that is it. The file is not saved. What do you mean by… _”open excel immediately”_ … and … _“without saving excel”_ ?